# Paparazzi running ./gradlew testDebug verifyPaparazziDebug does not generate report htlm

Tags: android, snapshot-testing

I tried to run [Paparazzi](https://github.com/cashapp/paparazzi) snapshot tests via terminal using these commands:

`./gradlew clean assembleDebug testDebug verifyPaparazziDebug`

But this seems to skip `testDebug`. It is supposed to generate index.htlm in /app/build/reports/paparazzi/ folder but that folder is empty.

Running as below works fine:

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug testDebug

// wait for finish

./gradlew verifyPaparazziDebug
```

I just wonder why I can't run `testDebug verifyPaparazzi` in sequence in one command. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?